# OR statement in lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

What is the correct way to do something like this.

```
db.Tasks.Where(t => {t.CategoryId == 1 || t.CategoryId == 2) ||  t.CategoryId == 3)}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your brackets are just wrong at the moment, both in terms of curly braces and plain parentheses. You don't actually need any brackets within the expression - this is fine (reformatted for clarity):

```
var list = db.Tasks
             .Where(t => t.CategoryId == 1 || 
                         t.CategoryId == 2 ||
                         t.CategoryId == 3)
             .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A lambda expression is exactly that – it consists of a single ordinary *expression*.  (such as `a || b || c`)

Braces are for statements, not expressions.
Just remove the `{}` and that will work fine.

You also have some stray `)`.

Comment: Then explain `var list = db.Tasks.Where(t => { return t.CategoryId == 1; });`  ;)